# Move switch statement to text file

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

Here is my situation every time we add a new product to our catalog we need to go through add the product to this snippet and recompile the dll's, then push them out to all of the servers.

What I'd like to be able to do is to be able to just add a line to a text file that the DLL then reads in. To make things easy the file will reside in the same folder as the DLL's.  The main issue is there are several places that call this all of which pass in the productId, so changing that would not be feasible.

```
void AssignFunctions(int productId)
{
    switch (productId)
    {
        case 31:
            IsSpread = CalendarIsSpread;
            IsLeftPage = CalendarIsLeftPage;
            GetOppositePageNumber = GeneralGetOppositePageNumber;
            break;
        case 49:
        case 63:
        case 64:
        case 69:
        case 70:
        ...
        case 592: 
        case 630: 
        case 686: 
            IsSpread = NeverASpread;
            IsLeftPage = GeneralIsLeftPage;
            GetOppositePageNumber = GeneralGetOppositePageNumber;
            break;
        case 73:
            IsSpread = GeneralIsSpread;
            IsLeftPage = GeneralIsLeftPage;
            GetOppositePageNumber = GeneralGetOppositePageNumber;
            break;
        case 444:
        case 445:
            IsSpread = BookletIsSpread;
            IsLeftPage = BookletLeftPage;
            GetOppositePageNumber = BookletGetOppositePageNumber;
            break;
        default:
            IsSpread = GeneralIsSpread;
            IsLeftPage = GeneralIsLeftPage;
            GetOppositePageNumber = GeneralGetOppositePageNumber;
            break;
    }
}
```

Another scenario would be to take the productId and compare it to the text file and then act accordingly. In that case the call would look something like this:

```
void AssignFunctions(int productId)
{
    //Do Something here to get the productSpreadType

    switch (productSpreadType)
    {
        case 1:
            IsSpread = CalendarIsSpread;
            IsLeftPage = CalendarIsLeftPage;
            GetOppositePageNumber = GeneralGetOppositePageNumber;
            break;
        case 2:
            IsSpread = NeverASpread;
            IsLeftPage = GeneralIsLeftPage;
            GetOppositePageNumber = GeneralGetOppositePageNumber;
            break;
        case 3:
            IsSpread = GeneralIsSpread;
            IsLeftPage = GeneralIsLeftPage;
            GetOppositePageNumber = GeneralGetOppositePageNumber;
            break;
        case 4:
            IsSpread = BookletIsSpread;
            IsLeftPage = BookletLeftPage;
            GetOppositePageNumber = BookletGetOppositePageNumber;
            break;
        default:
            IsSpread = GeneralIsSpread;
            IsLeftPage = GeneralIsLeftPage;
            GetOppositePageNumber = GeneralGetOppositePageNumber;
            break;
    }
}
```

In this case the text file would look something like this:

```
31 1
49 2
63 2
...
73 3
444 4
```

If the productId is not listed it would just then perform the default action.

.NET is not my forte and it takes a good half day every time we add new products to remember how to update this. As I am the only one with Visual Studio running on Windows the task always fall to me. With the exception of having to make this change we don't have to touch the code base, so it would be nice to not have to build the DLL's every time and be able to pass the task of making sure this gets updated to one of our junior developers, who make are the ones responsible for adding new products.

Comment: You should probably look into configuration files.

Comment: [Switch Statements Smells](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwitchStatementsSmell) "Most times you see a switch statement, you should consider polymorphism"

Comment: What are CalendarIsSpread, GeneralIsLeftPage, BookletGetOppositePageNumber? Properties? Of which types?. You should include more contextual data.

Comment: This looks like a simple mapping between ids and a couple of fixed properties. This could be handled by a simple dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

C# is a static language and is not meant for dynamic code like you're suggesting.
I would however consider a different design where you can read different categories from a database and act on them as categories rather than individual items with the same handling. 
Looks like you can group a lot of these together.

You can also consider a config file as the source for the categories.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little reflection magic:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        // Test Data
        DoProduct(31);      
        DoProduct(63);  
        DoProduct(49);
        DoProduct(49);
        DoProduct(61);
    }

    public static void DoProduct(int productId)
    {
        string data = "";
        bool methodExecuted = false;

        // I am loading the string "data" with test data for simplicity.
        // In real life, you'll load this from your file intead.
        data = data + "31 MyFirstFunction" + Environment.NewLine;
        data = data + "49 MySecondFunction" + Environment.NewLine;
        data = data + "63 MyThirdFunction" + Environment.NewLine;

        foreach (string str in data.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n").Replace('\r', '\n').Split('\n'))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                continue;

            int pid = int.Parse(str.Split(' ')[0]);
            string func = str.Split(' ')[1];

            if (pid != productId)
                continue;

            Type type = typeof(Program);

            MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

            MethodInfo method = methods.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Name.Equals(func));
            if (method == null) {
                continue;
            }

            method.Invoke(null, null);  
            methodExecuted = true;
        }

        if (!methodExecuted)
        {
            MyDefaultFunction();
        }
    }

    public static void MyFirstFunction() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is MyFirstFunction()!");
    }

    public static void MySecondFunction() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is MySecondFunction()!");
    }

    public static void MyThirdFunction() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is MyThirdFunction()!");
    }

    public static void MyDefaultFunction() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is MyDefaultFunction()!");
    }
}
```

This will allow you to create a text file, like this:

```
31 MyFunction
63 AnotherFunction
...
```

And using reflection, it will execute the correct function every time you pass in a product id. If the product id is not in the text file, it will call the default function.

Here is a fiddle of it in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Atpq7

Answer (score 0):

If you really must use a text file you could load it into a multiple value dictionary using a struct, then perform a search on that dictionary

assuming test data of the following in a text file called test.txt:

```
1,value1,value2
2,value1,value2
...
```

you could do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    // declare test data
    public static int[] _products = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // Searchable value dictionary to be filled by file
    static Dictionary<int,Values> d = new Dictionary<int,Values>();      
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Read the file line by line into the dictionary          
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test\\test.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] values = line.Split(',');
            int productId = int.Parse(values[0]);
            Values v = new Values();
            v.Value1 = values[1];
            v.Value2 = values[2];

            d.Add(productId, v);
        }
        file.Close();

        // check our loaded config file
        foreach (int p in _products)
        {

            if (d.Keys.Contains(p))
            {
                // we've found a match in the file
                // your logic goes here!
            }
            else
            {
                // no match was found
                // handle missing data
            }
        }

    }

    // struct to hold your data from text file
    struct Values
    {
        public string Value1;
        public string Value2;
    }

}
```